# How to Allow multishipping checkout for Guest Customer in magenot 2

Tags: magento2, checkout, multishipping

I want to allow multi-shipping checkout for guest customers in Magento 2. So can you hint at how I can achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: you mean you want to disallow for registered customers and only enable it for guests?

Comment: No, i want to enable multishipping checkout method for both customer(registered customers and guests)

Comment: Mohit Patel are you able to do achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

The multishipping method is enabled by default in Magento (see screenshot).

[image]

However, Luma theme does not show any link to load it. From your current shop, if you have a basket that is not empty and you hit the url `<magento_url>/multishipping/checkout`, you will see the multicheckout starting. Then, you will need to add to your template a link for this multishipping url to start instead of the default checkout url.

Comment: Yes, default Magento is provided but only for registered customers, not guest customers. So I want to enable it with a guest customer.